# Windows 10 Photos app: how to fix "It looks like you don't have permission to save changes to this file"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

I created a video (`.avi` file) using CamStudio and saved it. Now I am trying to trim the video using Windows 10 Photos app. After I clicked "Save a copy" it says: "It looks like you don't have permission to save changes to this file" followed by "Try saving a copy instead".

[image]

This is very confusing because 1) the video is created by myself using CamStudio (so I should have the permissions), and 2) I am already saving a copy (so I am *not* "saving changes to this file").

Is it a bug? How to fix?

Comment: Where are you trying to save the file?  No issue like this here.

Comment: @John `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\My CamStudio Videos`.